# Maxwell-Boltzman speed distribution

Tags: statistical-mechanics, velocity

For a class assignment, I have to do a Barnes-Hut Galaxy simulation.

The assignment includes:

> The dots' velocities following the Maxwell distribution with typical velocity of $$v={\left<v\right>}^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ and that mean that each of the velocity vector components vave normal distribution with mean zero and $$\sigma = \frac{v}{\sqrt{3}}$$

The "*dots*" it mentions represent stars in the simulated galaxy.

Someone can explain to me the meaning of that?  How the mean of all the components can be zero if, for example, $V=85\,\mathrm{kmh}$?

Comment: Are you sure that this is copied correctly?  I mean I'd have expected for it to say$${v}_{\text{RMS}} ~ \equiv ~ \sqrt{{\left<v^{2}\right>}}\,,$$where $``{v}_{\text{RMS}}"$ is the "_root-mean square_" of the velocities.  It's basically just like taking a normal average, except you square all of the numbers first, then take the square-root at the end.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure it is $\langle v\rangle=0$ and not $\langle v_z\rangle=\langle v_\phi\rangle=0$ (cf [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/308268/25301)).

Comment: This question was cross-posted and answered on [computational science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29885/barnes-hut-method-for-gravitational-dynamics). I believe that SE discourages cross-posting to avoid duplication of effort, so maybe the OP could consider deleting this version of the question?