# Initial particle configuration of a spiral galaxy for $N$-Body simulation

Tags: astrophysics, simulations

I coded an $N$-Body tree algorithm. Now I want to test the code for a particle configuration which represents at the beginning a sphere with radius $R=1$. All $N$ particles are randomly distributed inside the sphere. For the mass I chose $m_i=\frac{1}{N}$.

Now the difficult part to me, the right velocity: I want the sphere to rotate around its own axis in such a way that the sphere neither explodes (centrifugal force > gravitational force) nor implodes (centrifugal force < gravitational force). As a result for large simulation time $T_{MAX}$ I would expect a formation as known from a spiral galaxy.

So, I know what I have to consider, but I do not know how to get the right velocities for such a particle distribution. How should I possibly start? I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308100/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94845/

Comment: The answer to [Distribution of orbital velocities in a disk galaxy for N-body simulation?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308100/) is presumably also the answer to this one.

Comment: In an N-body code, a spherical distribution of particles will not settle into a disk.  Disks form from gas (hydrodynamic) physics, not newtonian dynamics.  An initially spherical distribution would better describe a star-cluster or globular-cluster.  KyleKanos' linked answer describes how you can *start* with a disk however.

Comment: @KyleKanos I saw those posts but did not find them very useful. I still do not know how to define $\vec{v}$. I can probably use the following equation $\vec{v}(\phi (r) = \sqrt{\frac{3GM(a^2-\frac{r^2}{3})}{a^3}}$. But how do I get $\vec{v}_x$ and $\vec{v}_y$ from it?

Comment: @Samuel doesn't my second link there say how to obtain the Cartesian coordinates from the spherical in the last few lines?